# Let f be a function analytic in the disk D...(Hint: apply Cauchy’s Integral Formula to a circle centered at 2i).

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be a function analytic in the disk $D = \{z\, : \,|z − 3 − 2i|\leq 5\}$ that satisfies $|f(z)| \leq 3$ for
all $ z \in D$.
Prove that $|f^{(4)} (2i)| \leq 4.5$.

(Hint: apply Cauchy’s Integral Formula to a circle centered
at $2i$).

- If a function is analytic it means that the complex derivative exists at every

  point. I know that i is a distance and i know what formula to use for the the

Cauchy's integral but I don't know how to type it here. I will try to put an

image or link of the formula and hopefully you can see. That is all I have. [1]:

i.stack.imgur.com/OZErN.png .

Can you help me solve It?